# Count the number of different characters in the first 150 characters of two cells

Tags: excel-formula

I have two pieces of text in cells A2 and B2 which I want to check to see if the first 150 characters match and the last 150 characters match. If the two do not match then is there a way to get a count of the number of characters that are different between those initial 150 characters that were compared.

[Example of cells and the formulas I have currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjc16.png)

Comment: So you have the Left and right correct?  change the `2` to `150`

Comment: Using formula will be a little bit complex to evaluate the 3 scenarios.

Comment: How are you planing `to get a count of the number of characters that are different between those initial 150 characters that were compared.`? I'ts not clear for me.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I noticed the 2 about 10 seconds after I posted the question so that's now changed.

Comment: Hi David, I did some digging around and found the following which kind of gets me one step of the way: =SUM(1*(MID(A2,ROW(1:100),1)<>MID(B2,ROW(1:100),1) )) but this counts the MID and doesn't account for anything more than one change. Forgive me as I am a newbie to Excel.

Comment: That is the correct formula, just change the `100` to `150` and it will count the differences in the first 150 characters.  See my answer below.

Comment: Oh and yours is an array formula that needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: Thanks for this Scott. It works perfectly. Just one question I have off the back of this and that is how to stop the 1:150 increasing as I drag the formula down the sheet?

Comment: You should have put that comment on my answer, or use the `@` in front of my name, I would have seen it sooner.  See my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the count of mismatch in the first 150:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(A2,ROW($1:$150),1)<>MID(B2,ROW($1:$150),1)))
```

In the last 150:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(A2,LEN(A2) + 1 - ROW($1:$150),1)<>MID(B2,LEN(B2) + 1 - ROW($1:$150),1)))
```

[image]